# Make counter variable in each method increase itself

Tags: ruby

How to make `a` variable within .each method increasable, so the output would be 1, 2, 3...Instead of this:

```
<% @all_posts.each do |p, a = 0| %>
  <% a += 1 %>
  <%= a %>
<% end %>
```

Output:  1, 1, 1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `each_with_index` instead of `each`
Only caveat: the index starts with 0.

```
<% @all_posts.each_with_index do |p, a| %>
  <%= a %>
  <%= p.name %>
<% end %>
```

See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index

Comment: Thank you, I feel kinda ashamed for asking such question, I'll accept this answer as soon as SO let's me. Btw is there any way to make starting index some other value rather than 0?

Answer (score 1):

To make it accessible, initialize it outside of the loop.

```
<% a = 0 %>
<% @all_posts.each do |p| %>
  <% a += 1 %>
  <%= a %>
<% end %>
```

But a better way is:

```
<% @all_posts.each.with_index(1) do |p, a| %>
  <%= a %>
<% end %>
```